# How to pivot chart 2 data types

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, pivot-table

I am trying to find a way to capture 2 data types in one pivot table so I can make a single chart.

I have a year's worth of survey data (survey had 5 questions with scores of 1 - 4) and I'd like to capture the average score per question per month AND a count of how many surveys were taken during the month.

I can easily capture the average scores and display that in a cluster chart. The dilemma is that I also need **ONE** column that counts the number of surveys for that month.

My source data includes a Unique Count column but when I add that to the Values section of the pivot table, it adds a count next to each question (thus, it has 5 columns of counts).

So far, the only way I've been able to do it is by creating 2 pivot tables (one with questions and response averages and one with the count) and then setting up a grid to combine that data into 1 table.  This is clumsy and would be difficult (but not impossible) to automate.

I've searched online for the following possibilities but haven't been successful: (1) 2 data types in one pivot table (what I described above); (2) 2 pivot tables in a single chart; (3) Consolidate 2 pivot tables into one.

NOTE:  I WANT TO ADD A FILE EXAMPLE BUT I CAN'T SEE HOW.  PLEASE ADVISE.  Just in case, here is a picture of part of the file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2013 or later, you can use the DataModel to do this, regardless of whether you have a version that includes PowerPivot or not. You simply need to add the original table to the DataModel, then write 6 measures (5 of which filter the data by response, and the 6th generates a Grand Total) then put those 6 measures into your PivotTable Values area.

Here's an example, using some sample data I just whipped up:

[image]

...and here's the measures that I used to do this:

[image]

For a great video showing how to do this, check out Mike Girvin's ExcelIsFun YouTube channel, specifically https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVVK-8QZC1M

Another alternative is to use the GETPIVOTDATA function to return the values  from the two individual PivotTables you are currently using to the block you are currently feeding the chart.

Lastly, I'd suggest NOT displaying the data like this, but instead breaking it into two charts. For instance, both of these were created using 'traditional' PivotTables:

[image]

...and the advantage to the viewer is that it's much easier to follow monthly trends by response type when all similar responses are grouped together.

Comment: Somehow, though, using DAX or the Data Model to build a pivot table adds constraints to the pivot chart, such as not being able to format the X axis tick labels. I don't know if this is by design or a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this time we only have Excel 2010 (I know, right?!).  PowerPivot isn't really an option because the file gets sent to someone else who won't have PP.  I don't know anything about DAX.

Comment: Personally, I agree with you but the client wants both data sets in the one chart.  UGH!  I think I'm stuck having to pass the results through either the small, manual table shown in the example above or passing it through a different sheet that reformats it as Jon described below.  Heavy sigh.  Thanks for the ideas, though.

Comment: Clients are the worst. I'm with Jeff on using two charts.

Comment: Cool.  GETPIVOTDATA will help if using the intermediate table

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice example of using DAX to get what you want from a pivot table, and there are some pivot tables you may need that you have to use DAX for. But you don't even need to use the data model or DAX for this simple case.

Create a pivot table with date in the rows area and each of the survey questions in the values area, and show them as average. These are your survey averages.

Then drag any one of the survey questions (doesn't matter which, and let's assume that each submitted survey has a submitted response for each question) to the values area, and show it as count. This is your survey count column.

Now make your pivot chart. If desired, the Count can go onto the secondary axis.

One advantage to not using a DAX/Data Model pivot table is that you can format the dates in the pivot table using the Field Settings dialog (instead of having to format the underlying range), and the dates along the horizontal axis of the chart will honor this format, or you can format them however you like using the normal Format Axis task pane. The DAX/Data Model pivot chart does not let you format the axis labels.

Comment: Now this sounds interesting. I’ll try this I the morning. :)

Comment: Jon,  I tried to implement what you suggested but the source data is set up differently (I added a screenshot of that to my original post).  Worst case scenario I can add another tab that re-organized the results as needed but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.  Any other ideas (that don't involve add-ins)?

Comment: Jon: I take it your approach works where the source data is cross-tabulated data?

Comment: By cross-tabbed, do you mean one column in the raw data for each survey question? I believe that's how I set it up. It's on a different computer in a different room, so I'll have to check later.

Comment: If the data is not cross-tabbed, then adding the survey field a second time to the values area gives me five columns with the quantity. Messy, redundant, but it still kind of works.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the issue and I can't find a way to suppress the redundant columns.  This also makes it difficult to set the number of surveys as a secondary axis (the black line in my chart image).

Comment: Yes, this **is** the problem, isn't it. You could try to hide columns, but pivot tables don't give you the option to hide data in hidden rows and columns from the pivot chart. Each of the extra columns gives you the same data, so the lines coincide. You can delete the extra legend entries (one click to select the legend, a second click to select the legend entry, then Delete), but I have a feeling they'll return when the pivot is refreshed, and it still says Count - Was Professional. Guess Microsoft needs to fix this one.

Comment: As I mentioned to Jeff above, I think I'm pretty much stuck.  No matter how I look at it, I'm going to have to pass the data through to some other structure (what you described above or the extra table shown in the original screenshot) in order to get it into one chart.  Maybe I'll have more options once we upgrade to O365.  Thanks for the ideas/suggestions, though.

Comment: In Office 365, which means Excel 2016, you get the Power Query approach Jeff described. I used Excel 2016 without Power Query, and you see where I got.